# PHP auto assign IP

Tags: php, mysql, ip

I'm creating a little module for my web application and I need something that automatically assign an IP from a pool I implemented.

I tried to add the database as:

```
pool = 172.16.0.0
mask = 20
```

I want to add users and assign automatically 1 ip from this pool and do no repeat it.

Basically I'm doing and "auto-config" module for our technicians that only have to enter the client name, client id and client location.

I was thinking about IP segmentation, for example

in the database assign:

```
segment1 = 172
segment2 = 16
segment3 = 0
```

And in another database insert the 3 first segments and append the last number between 1-254

Idk if anyone tried this before (surely yes) and how I can do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, you should determine how many IP you can adress with a mask. I think of a function that would be called `getIPrangeFromMask(int $mask)`. For the least I know, you can find some information on the wikipedia page of [Subnetwork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork). Then, when you know your IP range, you just have to loop foreach IP range, and foreach you check if it has been adressed for one of your users. If not, you adress it for the current user that need an IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I got it with the help of ip2long

I save in the database the first IP from the pool and the last one.

Then I convert it to decimal with ip2long

When I want to use I check the last pool ip and the last_used_ip and just do last_used_ip+1.

```
if($checkCliente == 0){
        if($checkTelefono == 0){
                //Faltan checks para comprobar usuario Asterisk y PPPoE
                $pool_result = $conn->query("SELECT ultima,ip_final FROM ip_pools WHERE id='$pool_id'");
                if($pool_result ->num_rows == '1'){
                        $row = $pool_result->fetch_assoc();
                        $ultima_ip = ip2long($row['ultima']);
                        $ip_final = ip2long($row['ip_final']);
                        if($ultima_ip !== $ip_final){

                                $ip_gestion = (ip2long($row['ultima']) + 1);
                                $ip_gestion = long2ip($ip_gestion);
                                if($conn->query("INSERT INTO clients(nombre,num_cliente,telefono,poblacion,direccion,ip_gestion,password,usuario_pppoe,usuario_asterisk) VALUES('$nombre', '$num_cliente', '$telefono', '$poblacion', '$direccion', '$ip_gestion', '$password', '$usuario_pppoe', '$usuario_asterisk')")){
                                        $conn->query("UPDATE ip_pools SET ultima='$ip_gestion'");
                                        $alert = 'success';
                                        $mensaje = 'El cliente '.$nombre.' con el número de cliente '.$num_cliente.' se ha creado correctamente';

                                        $export = '__exportar_resultados__';
                                } else {
                                        $alert = "danger";
                                        $mensaje = "Ha ocurrido un error al intentar introducir los datos en la base de datos.";
                                }
                        } else {
                                $alert = 'danger';
                                $mensaje = 'El pool de IP\'s seleccionado está lleno<br />Porfavor, seleccione otro.';
                        }
                } else {
                        $alert = 'danger';
                        $mensaje = 'No hay ningún Pool de IP\'s seleccionado';
                }
        } else {
                $alert = 'danger';
                $mensaje = 'El número de teléfono '.$telefono.' ya existe.';
        }
} else {
        $alert = 'danger';
        $mensaje = 'El número de cliente '.$num_cliente.' ya existe.';
}
```